# Animating a Canvas Element's Dimensions

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm trying to animate the dimensions of a canvas element (for example, increasing its height). The issue is that the canvas element requires a fixed width and height for it to work properly, so pure CSS animations won't work.

What would be the most efficient way to animate this, while still keeping a decent frame rate?

Comment: Do you really need to modify the element's height ? Can't you just update the content's height ?

Comment: @Kaiido Unfortunately, yes. The idea is that the canvas takes up like half the page, but the user can click on it to expand it to the full size of the page. I considered making the canvas a background image of the container, but it also needs to be interactive.

Comment: changing an canvas element's `width` and `height` properties is unfortunately slow since it will reset all the properties of the attached context. One way could be to do it via CSS, wait for the transitionend event (still not widely supported), and update the properties only after the css animation has done its job. This way, your canvas would probably be a bit off during the transition, but ok afterward.

Comment: Actually you don't even have to wait for he transition end, just update the properties to the target size beforehand, it will be correct at the end of the transition.

Comment: @Kaiido I managed to sort of achieve this by making the canvas the size of the viewport and absolutely positioned and centered inside of a wrapper element with overflow hidden. Now I'm able to animate the height of the wrapper to my desired size. The only issue is that this is not a very efficient method to do animations since height [triggers layout](https://csstriggers.com/height). Would you happen to know of a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS3 animation, it's working...

```js
$(".btn").click(function(){
  $("#myCanvas").addClass("animated-class");
});
```

```css
#myCanvas{
  border:solid 1px black;
}

.animated-class{
animation:test 1s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes test{
from{height:100px}
to{height:300px}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn">Full page</button>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100"></canvas>
```

Comment: That messes with how the canvas renders things: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zzZXYZ

Comment: Yep that's what @Kaiido told you. Change the canvas properties will affect the render...